# chart.js - hide points in line chart and show only tooltip

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I would like hide points and show only tooltips in line chart.

I don't found settings to do this.

Any help?

[image]

I tried set `pointRadius` to 0 in `dataset`, but this remove point and tooltip.

```
{ 
        data: [-1.1, -1.11, 1.11, 5.11, 9.11, 5.11],
        label: 'Rent',
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#3664AF",
        borderWidth: 2,
        backgroundColor:"#3664AF",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        pointBorderColor: "#3664AF",
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 0
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did function in `pointStyle` and `pointRadius` to build point or line based on dataset index.

```
{ 
        data: [-1.1, -1.11, 1.11, 5.11, 9.11, 5.11],
        
        label: 'Rent',
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#3664AF",
        borderWidth: 2,
        backgroundColor:"#3664AF",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        pointBorderColor: "#3664AF",
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
        hideInLegendAndTooltip: false,
        pointStyle: function(context) {
            let index = context.dataIndex;
            if(index == 5) {
                return 'circle';
            } else {
                return 'line';
            }

        },
        pointRadius: function(context) {
            let index = context.dataIndex;
            if(index == 5) {
                return 3;
            }else {
                return 1;
            }
        },
        
    }
```

[image]